# asymptotic notation on both side of equation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I know what does `f(n)=theta(g(n))` or `f(n)=BighOh(g(n))` mean but getting confused when there are something like `theta(f(n)) = theta(g(n))`. i.e. when the asymptotic notation is on the both side. Can anyone please explain what does this mean?

I got this, when solving a problem like this: there are 3 algorithm

```
X : is polynomial
Y : is exponential
Z : is double exponential
```

There are 4 opitions in the answers :

```
a) theta(X) = theta(Y)
b) theta(X) = theta(Z)
c) theta(Y) = theta(Z)
d) BigOh(Z) = X
```

The correct answer is option C.
Can anyone please explain

Comment: Possibly off-topic for SO, perhaps this is a question better suited for [Programmers](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)? See this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165519)

Comment: I'd think [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place.

Comment: @haxxxton when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat, good point, I had intended to communicate that the post should be _moved_ to Programmers :)

Answer (score 1):

`C = θ(D)`, in simple language means there are 2 tight bounds say, `A` and `B` such that `C` can be sandwiched between them. That is `A <= C <= B`.

`A` and `B` depend upon `D`. That is, `A = aD` and `B = bD` where, `a` and `b` are constants.

In general `theta(P) = theta(Q)` means the bounds specified by `P (aP and bP)` and `Q (aQ and bQ)`

- are equal i.e, `aP = aQ`   and `bP = bQ`,   or
- one of the bounds in contained inside another 
  i.e, `aP<=aQ<=bQ<=bP` or `aQ<=aP<=bP<=bQ`.

  ```
  Y = exponential = 1.5^x
  Z = double exponential = 1.5^1.5^x
  ```

Here, it can be seen from the the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function#/media/File:Double_Exponential_Function.PNG) that the bounds on exponential function (`1.5^x`) can contain the bounds of double exponential function (`1.5^1.5^x`).  Hence `θ(Y) = θ(Z)`. In fact the bounds of exponential function can be used as bounds of double exponential function.